# How to speed up this aggregated query that only needs the latest 2 documents per category

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, grouping

I have a collection with a few million documents, thats grows with a couple of thousands each day. Each document in the collection has up to 200 properties. What I would like to do is to create a query that can gives me the last 2 documents per category. This is something I have accomplished but it's very slow.

Consider the following structure:

```
db.createCollection('testing')
db.testing.createIndex({time:-1})
db.testing.createIndex({category:1})
```

With the following example documents:

```
db.testing.insert( { time: ISODate("2018-03-26T23:00:00.000Z"), category: 'a', 'value1':0 } )
db.testing.insert( { time: ISODate("2018-03-26T23:00:00.000Z"), category: 'b', 'value1':30 } )
db.testing.insert( { time: ISODate("2018-03-26T23:00:00.000Z"), category: 'c', 'value1':10 } )
db.testing.insert( { time: ISODate("2018-03-27T23:00:00.000Z"), category: 'a', 'value1':0 } )
db.testing.insert( { time: ISODate("2018-03-27T23:00:00.000Z"), category: 'b', 'value1':20 } )
db.testing.insert( { time: ISODate("2018-03-27T23:00:00.000Z"), category: 'c', 'value1':20 } )
db.testing.insert( { time: ﻿ISODate("2018-03-28T23:00:00.000Z"), category: 'a', 'value1':10 } )
db.testing.insert( { time: ISODate("2018-03-28T23:00:00.000Z"), category: 'b', 'value1':10 } )
db.testing.insert( { time: ISODate("2018-03-28T23:00:00.000Z"), category: 'c', 'value1':10 } )
```

I have the following query:

```
db.getCollection('testing').aggregate([
    { // Added a match hoping this would speed up the query because I know the last 2 documents are never older then 10 days
        '$match': {
            time:{'$lte':new Date(),'$gte':new Date(Date()-10)}
        }
    },
   { // Add sort because I want the most recent documents
        '$sort': {
            'time' : -1 
        }
    },
    { 
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$category',
            'docs': { '$push': '$$ROOT' },
        }
    },
    {
        '$project': {
            'top_two': { 
                '$slice': ['$docs', 2]
            }
        }
    }
], {allowDiskUse:true})
```

The $match part in the query only seems to be executed after the grouping which makes everything very slow (minutes of execution time) on my big collection with millions of documents. I did get a tip to speed up my query from a community member. He suggested: "The $push in the $group stage can use the $slice right away. That way, each category will have at most 2 items period."

However I can't seem to get this working or to find an example on how to do this. But I can definitely understand how this would be very beneficial in terms of execution time.

What is the best way to speed up this query?

Comment: What is the cardinality of the `category` field? Do you expect to have a lot (i.e. thousands) of categories?

Comment: Also there is currently no method to use `$push` and `$slice` together in a single aggregation stage. The community member may refer to the `$push` in the update operation, where you can have the `$slice`modifier. This is not available in the aggregation pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I just compared your query results with and without `$sort` stage. Both look same:
[image]

So, `$sort` have zero impact on your output. It means that it uses your `time` index to arrange them in the output if I dont specify `$sort`. Just remove `$sort` which is not necessary in your case. Your index is already sorting results for you. How? because you're using index on `time` field and you wanted to sort based on `time` (in the same descending order). So it works in descending order even when you don't specify `$sort` explicitly.  Hope you understood!

Read here for more: [Use indexes for sorting](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/)